# Python - How to use MNIST to predict a np.darray with different shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

url = 'http://static.bn-static.com/pg/0rmrKX8jCvpmF8b7ab+coivEApi2iNNpgVTrfyFFA0g==.gif'
img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen((url)))
img = img.convert('1').convert('L') #convert to graysclae

# Optional to visualize it all:
# plt.imshow(img)
# plt.show()
# a = array(img)
# a = a.transpose()
# np.place(a,a==0,1)
# np.place(a,a==255,0)

# Croping only one number out of it and vectorize it with binary values.
data = array(img.crop((7, 0, 14, 15)))
np.place(data, data == 0, 1)
np.place(data, data == 255, 0)
plt.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
# visualize crop
plt.show()
# visualize matrix
data
```

I want to use Tensorflow or whatever is needed to predict which number is in this cropped image so I can keep doing that until all numbers can be predicted.

The array properties are pretty different from MNIST database since this is not a 28x28 image.

Is there any way that I can figure out linear transformations to do it for me or something?

Thanks

Comment: Is using a model trained on MNIST important do you? You could use any of the libraries for optical character recognition (OCR) available for Python to achieve the same result much more easily instead. Especially considering the fact that your numbers are not hand-written.

Comment: @MartinValgur any answers that solve this problem would be super helpful but it would be really great if I could learn how to adapt the MNIST stuff to recognize numbers from another source.

BTW I've tried pytesseract and I ended up with many unmatching numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a resize operation before the first convolution:

```
x = tf.image.resize_images(x, [28, 28])
```

So that can accept different image sizes. Make sure your input array has shape:

```
x.get_shape().as_list() == [ None, width, height, channels]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not sure how to implement what you've said. I'm sorry but I'm not experienced in Python and Tensorflow.
I tried: 
`url = 'http://static.bn-static.com/pg/0rmrKX8jCvpmF8b7ab+coivEApi2iNNpgVTrfyFFA0g==.gif'`
`img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen((url)))`
`img = img.convert('1').convert('L') #convert to grayscale`
`data2 = img.crop((7,0,14,15))`
`x = tf.image.resize_images(data2, [28,28])`

But I'm getting: ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: <PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=L size=7x15 at 0x23918CF2EB8> - got shape [15, 7], but wanted [].